# How to get the selected texts id with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, select

I have a select list like this:

```
<select id="takimlar" placeholder="Randevu Alacağınız Takımınızı Seçiniz">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Randevu Alacak Takım</option>
        </select>
```

options are coming from the database with this code

```
    var formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("email", kullaniciEmail);

    console.log("Form Data Bilgileri")
    console.log(formData);
    //kapat();
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "../backend/kullanici-takimlari-getir.php", true);
    xhr.send(formData);

    xhr.onload = function () {
        console.log(this.response);

        var res = this.response;
        res = JSON.parse(res);
        console.log(res)


        res.forEach(takim => {
        console.log(takim)   
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = takim.takimadi;
        option.value = takim.takimadi;
        var select = document.getElementById("takimlar");
        select.appendChild(option);
    });
```

So when I choose an option from the select list on my site I want to take the id (that comes from the database) of the selected option (not text or its value).

How can I do it?

Comment: Put the id to data-* attribute of the option.

Comment: Or rather, set the ID for `option.value` to begin with, in stead of `takim.takimadi`. (Description so far does not sound as if you needed the option text to be duplicated in there for any other purpose.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use the text or value of an option, you have to set your own attribute.

```js
res.forEach(takim => {
  console.log(takim)   
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.text = takim.takimadi;
  option.value = takim.takimadi;
  option.setAttribute('data-id', 'YOUR_ID_HERE');
  var select = document.getElementById("takimlar");
  select.appendChild(option);
});
```

Then, get the attribute `data-id` value of the `selectedIndex`.

```js
var select = document.getElementById("takimlar");
var id = select.options[select.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-id');
// id contains the value of the data-id attribute
```